# getLatestBlockhash is returning older blockhash

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized") is returning 3 months older lastValidBlockHeight, what could be issue here?

Answer (score 1):

"Works on my machine" - if all you're really doing is calling `connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")`, then it's most likely an issue with your RPC provider and you should contact them. Try one of the RPCs provided by Solana as a sanity check:

```
// Switch out devnet for whichever network you're using
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
const bh = connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized")
```

Note that the Solana default RPCs are rate limited, so don't use them in prod.